# Can't able to boot Ubuntu from USB

Tags: 14.04, windows-7

I am using HP Z400 Workstation with Windows 7. I want to completely move on to Ubuntu. I have made my usb bootable through "Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.6.1" and the computer and boot through USB/FLASH drive but it show a message for a second which says USB drive is booting and then Windows start's normally. I have search on internet but I can't find the solution. Let me know How to boot the Ubuntu from USB drive.